# how to add dropdownlist to kendo pop up editor if the add button is pressed

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

in my kendo grid when I want to add new record the add window pops up,i want to add a dropdown list there,because I need this drop downlist only if I want to add a new record,the fowlloing approach does not work,means I cant see the dopdown list:

```
edit:function(e) { if (e.model.isNew() ) {    $("DeviceType" )
                              .appendTo(container)
                              .kendoDropDownList({                                    
                               dataTextField: "Text",
                               dataValueField: "Text",
                               valuePrimitive: true,
                               dataSource: mydata_deviceType,}}}
```

my grid fields:

```
  columns: [
                                     { field: 'DeviceIP', title: 'DeviceIP', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceIP' },
                                     { field: 'Producer', title: 'Producer', width: '80px', id: 'Producer' },//editor: ProductNameDropDownEditor,
                                     { field: 'Model', title: 'Model', width: '220px', id: 'Model' },
                                     { field: 'DeviceType', title: 'DeviceType', width: '100px', id: 'DeviceType', editor: deviceTypesList },
                                     { field: 'Description', title: 'Description', width: '220px' },
                                     { field: 'Username', title: 'Username', width: '120px' },
                                     { field: 'Password', title: 'Password', width: '100px' },
                                     { field: 'PublicIP', title: 'PublicIP', width: '120px', id: 'PublicIP' },
                                     { field: 'TurbineId', title: 'TurbineId', width: '120px', id: 'TurbineId', hidden: true },
                                     { field: 'device_id', title: 'device_id', width: '120px', id: 'deviceid', hidden: true },
                                     { field: 'ModelProducer', title: 'Producer/Model', hidden: true, editor: modelProducer },
                                     {
                                         command: ["edit"], title: "&nbsp;"

                                     }
                            ],
```

the modelProducer function:

```
  function modelProducer(container, options) {


                           var t = modelProducerResult;

                            $('<input  name="ModelProducer" id="ModelProducer" data-type="string" style="width: 100%"\">')
                            .appendTo(container)
                            .kendoDropDownList({


                               dataSource: modelProducerResult,
                                dataTextField: "model",
                               dataValueField: "model",
                                valuePrimitive: true,                                   
                                change: upnChange

                            });

                            debugger;

                        }
```

Comment: There is no jQuery selector like $("DeviceType" ), You should use name selector  like this $("input [name=DeviceType]" ).

Comment: @R.K.Saini even   $('<input  name="DeviceType" id="DeviceType" data-type="string" \">')  does not work

Comment: Is the field with this name (DeviceType) exist in your grid?. And make sure it is editable as well

Comment: @R.K.Saini edited the question,yes its in my grid

Comment: As I can see you are using custom editor (deviceTypesList ) for DeviceType field, then why don't you add condition there to check if it is edit or add mode. Base on the mode return appropriate editor

Comment: @R.K.Saini can please tell me how to do that?its 3 days im dealing with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append editor based on mode add/or edit .
Just change your editor function like this :

```
function deviceTypesList(container, options) {
    if (options.model.isNew()) {
        $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
                .appendTo(container)
                .kendoDropDownList({
                    dataTextField: "Text",
                    dataValueField: "Text",
                    valuePrimitive: true,
                    dataSource: mydata_deviceType
                });
    }
    else
    {
        $('<input type="text" class="k-input k-textbox" name="DeviceType"">')
                .appendTo(container);
    }
}
```

Here is a working demo http://dojo.telerik.com/IReWe

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: its great but as you see in my question I have another function ,look at my grid please,the other function is modelProducer,wher should I put that in your approach?and that function bind my second dropdownlist based on the first function(deviceType)

Comment: I don't think you need to change that function. Although you can get value of the DeviceType using option.model.DeviceType  and change dropdown accordingly

Comment: @thanks,and  $('<input name="' + options.field + '"/>')
  by option.field you mean what?should I write something there?

Comment: No, option.field in custom editor contains name of the field on which you call your custom editor , So you don't need to change that.